# Input comma separated values in script of Python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, gitlab

I am new to this hence providing all the information I have, The script below takes the project id from GitLab and merges it automatically. However this script is made in such a way that it takes input of

```
./mergeMR --projectid 1
```

What I am looking for is, It should take input of multiple project ids, separated via commas like below:

```
./mergeMR --projectid 1,11,21
```

I am bit confused on how to achieve that and what are the changes which I need to make it in the script so that it will run efficiently.

The mergeMR.py script is :

```
import requests
import json
import argparse
import sys
import os
import urllib3
urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)

baseprojecturl='https://xxxxx.com/api/v4/projects/'
headers={'PRIVATE-TOKEN': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'}


def conflictsMR(project_id,mr_id):
    url=baseprojecturl+str(project_id)+'/merge_requests/'+str(mr_id)
    try:
      response = requests.get(url,headers=headers,verify=False)
      statuscode=response.status_code
      if(statuscode==200):
        response = requests.get(url,headers=headers,verify=False)
        json_response = response.json()
        return json_response['has_conflicts']
    except:
      print("An exception occurred")

def checkMR(project_id,mr_id):
    url=baseprojecturl+str(project_id)+'/merge_requests/'+str(mr_id)
    try:
      response = requests.get(url,headers=headers,verify=False)
      statuscode=response.status_code
      if(statuscode==200):
        response = requests.get(url,headers=headers,verify=False)
        json_response = response.json()
        sourcebranch=json_response["source_branch"]
        targetbranch=json_response["target_branch"]
        return (sourcebranch,targetbranch)
      else:
        print("Invalid Merge Request ID: "+str(mr_id))
    except:
      print("An exception occurred")

def getMRPipelineStatus(project_id,mr_id):
    url=baseprojecturl+project_id+'/merge_requests/'+str(mr_id)
    try:    
      response = requests.get(url,headers=headers,verify=False)
      json_response = response.json()
      if(json_response['head_pipeline']['status']=='success'):
        return True
      else:
        return False
    except:
      print("An exception occurred: getMRPipelineStatus for MR#"+str(mr_id))

def listMRDiscussions(project_id,mr_id):
    url=baseprojecturl+project_id+'/merge_requests/'+mr_id+'/discussions'
    try:    
      response = requests.get(url,headers=headers,verify=False)
      json_response = response.json()
      print(json_response)
    except:
      print("An exception occurred")

def line(char):
    print(char*50)

def approveMR(project_id,mr_id,status,comment):
    url=baseprojecturl+project_id+'/merge_requests/'+mr_id+'/approve'
    try:    
          response = requests.post(url,headers=headers,verify=False)
          json_response = response.json()
          print(json_response)
    except:
      print("An exception occurred") 

def mergeMR(project_id,mr_id):
     url=baseprojecturl+project_id+'/merge_requests/'+str(mr_id)+'/merge'
     try:    
         response = requests.put(url,headers=headers,verify=False)
         if(response.status_code==200):
           return True
         else:
           return False
     except:
        print("An exception occurred") 

def validatePRID(project_id):
    url=baseprojecturl+project_id
    try:    
         response = requests.get(url,headers=headers,verify=False)
         if(response.status_code==200):
           return True
         else:
           return False
    except:
        print("An exception occurred") 

def listMR(project_id):
    url=baseprojecturl+project_id+'/merge_requests'
    params={'state': 'opened'}
    try:    
         response = requests.get(url,headers=headers,params=params,verify=False)
         dict_as_json = str(response.text)
         json_array=json.loads(str(dict_as_json))
         mrs=[]
         for item in json_array:
           mrid=item['iid']
           mrs.append(mrid)
         return mrs
    except:
        print("An exception occurred") 

def getApprovalStatus(project_id,mr_id):
    url=baseprojecturl+project_id+'/merge_requests/'+str(mr_id)+'/approvals'
    try:
      response = requests.get(url,headers=headers,verify=False)
      json_response = response.json()
      print("Total No.of approvals left: "+str(json_response["approvals_left"]))
      if(json_response["approvals_left"]==0):
        if(listMRApprovers(project_id,mr_id)):
           return True
        else:
           print("return false here")
           return False
      else:
        return False
    except:
      print("Exception occurred during getApprovalStatus")

def createBranch(project_id,dest_branch,source_branch):
    url=baseprojecturl+project_id+'/repository/branches'
    params={'branch': dest_branch,'ref':source_branch}
    try:
      response = requests.post(url,headers=headers,params=params,verify=False)
      if(response.status_code==201):
        return True
      else:
        return False
    except:
       print("Exception occurred during createBranch")

def deleteBranch(project_id,branch):
    url=baseprojecturl+project_id+'/repository/branches'
    try:
        url=baseprojecturl+project_id+'/repository/branches/'+branch
        response = requests.delete(url,headers=headers,verify=False)
        if(response.status_code==204):
          return True
        else:
          return False
    except:
       print("Exception occurred during deleteBranch")

def checkBranch(project_id,branch):
    url=baseprojecturl+project_id+'/repository/branches/'+branch
    try:
      response = requests.get(url,headers=headers,verify=False)
      if(response.status_code==200):
        return True
      else:
        return False
    except:
       print("Exception occurred")

def listMRApprovers(project_id,mr_id):
    url=baseprojecturl+project_id+'/merge_requests/'+str(mr_id)+'/approval_state'
    try:
      response = requests.get(url,headers=headers,verify=False)
      json_response = response.json()
      no_of_rules=len(json_response["rules"])
      total_no_of_approvals=0
      no_of_approved=0
      sanity=False
      rule_names=[]
      for rule in range(no_of_rules):
        rule_names.append(json_response["rules"][rule]["name"])
      if("sanity approval" not in rule_names):
         sanity=True
      for rule in range(no_of_rules):
        if(not str(json_response["rules"][rule]["name"])=="sanity approval"):
           total_no_of_approvals=total_no_of_approvals+int(json_response["rules"][rule]["approvals_required"])
      for rule in range(no_of_rules):
        if(json_response["rules"][rule]["approved"]):
          if(str(json_response["rules"][rule]["name"])=="sanity approval"):
             sanity=True
          else:
             no_of_approved=len(json_response["rules"][rule]["approved_by"])
        else:
          ary=str(json_response["rules"][rule]["approved_by"])
          if(ary=='[]'):
            return False
      return True
    except:
      print("An exception occurred during listMRApprovers")

def main():
   parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
   parser.add_argument('--projectid', action='store', type=str, required=True)

   args = parser.parse_args()
   project_id=args.projectid.strip()
   line('=')
   if(validatePRID(project_id)):
     print("Project ID validation: SUCCESS")
     mrlist=listMR(project_id)
     if(mrlist):
       for mr in mrlist:
         line('-')
         print("Processing MR:"+str(mr))
         if(not conflictsMR(project_id,mr)):
           if(getMRPipelineStatus(project_id,mr)):
             print("Status of Pipeline for MR#"+str(mr)+" is SUCCESS")
             if(getApprovalStatus(project_id,mr)):
               if(mergeMR(project_id,mr)):
                 source_branch,target_branch=checkMR(project_id,mr)
                 if(checkBranch(project_id,source_branch)):
                   if(createBranch(project_id,"tobedeleted_"+source_branch,source_branch)):
                     if(deleteBranch(project_id,source_branch)):
                       print("Branch Renaming: SUCCESS")
                     else:
                       print("Branch Deletion: FAIL")
                   else:
                     print("Branch Creation: FAIL")
                 else:
                   print("Branch already removed")
               else:
                 print("Error Merging MR")
             else:
               print("Approval criteria not met for MR#"+str(mr)+", can't be merged")
           else:
             print("Status of Pipeline for MR#"+str(mr)+": FAIL")
         else:
           print("Conflicts for MR#"+str(mr)+" can't be merged")
     else:
       print("There are no MRs meeting the criteria")
   else:
     print("Project ID validation: FAIL")
   line('=')

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

I tried to achieve this by split function but maybe I am doing it wrong.

The main intention is that instead of running this script multiple times with different project ids, It should get this job done after running it only once for the specified project ids in commas.

Thanks in advance. If you require anything please add a comment and I will help.

The edited part

```
def main():
   parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
   parser.add_argument('--projectid', action='store', type=str, required=True)
   args = parser.parse_args()
   project_id=args.projectid.strip().split(',')
   for project_id in project_ids:
       process(project_id)

def process(projectid):
   line('=')
   if(validatePRID(project_id)):
     print("Project ID validation: SUCCESS")
     mrlist=listMR(project_id)
     if(mrlist):
       for mr in mrlist:
         line('-')
         print("Processing MR:"+str(mr))
         if(not conflictsMR(project_id,mr)):
           if(getMRPipelineStatus(project_id,mr)):
             print("Status of Pipeline for MR#"+str(mr)+" is SUCCESS")
             if(getApprovalStatus(project_id,mr)):
               if(mergeMR(project_id,mr)):
                 source_branch,target_branch=checkMR(project_id,mr)
                 if(checkBranch(project_id,source_branch)):
                   if(createBranch(project_id,"tobedeleted_"+source_branch,source_branch)):
                     if(deleteBranch(project_id,source_branch)):
                       print("Branch Renaming: SUCCESS")
                     else:
                       print("Branch Deletion: FAIL")
                   else:
                     print("Branch Creation: FAIL")
                 else:
                   print("Branch already removed")
               else:
                 print("Error Merging MR")
             else:
               print("Approval criteria not met for MR#"+str(mr)+", can't be merged")
           else:
             print("Status of Pipeline for MR#"+str(mr)+": FAIL")
         else:
           print("Conflicts for MR#"+str(mr)+" can't be merged")
     else:
       print("There are no MRs meeting the criteria")
   else:
     print("Project ID validation: FAIL")
   line('=')

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

I have edited the above part but seems like still it is not achieving its goal.
Have I done anything wrong ?

Comment: That's a lot of code, most of which is not directly relevant to the question. Can you try to narrow it to a [mcve]?

Comment: To help you pare down the code: your program starts at bottom which calls `def main()`. From there, we see a library `argparse` being called.  I found the docs for it: https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#nargs  I linked to `nargs` which will let you specify the multiplicity of the `projectid` argument.  That's really the only code that you need to show: `parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()`    `parser.add_argument('--projectid', action='store', type=str, required=True)`    `args = parser.parse_args()`

Comment: ^ this is a bit much work compared to better suggestion to split.  I was mostly providing my thought process of how I would frame this question.

Answer (score 2):

It's easy enough to extract the project as a list (btw, suggest you use the same variable name as argument to avoid confusion):

```
project_ids = args.projectid.strip().split(',')
```

Now you have to integrate that with the rest of the program, so callers accept a list or iterate through the list and process one at a time in a loop:

```
project_ids = args.projectid.strip().split(',')
for project_id in project_ids:
   ...
```

We discussed moving all the code to a function:

```
def process(projectid):
    # cut & paste everything from def main() starting from line('=') to the last line('=')
```

Then integrate the change I mentioned above so main just read:

```
 def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--projectid', action='store', type=str, required=True)
    args = parser.parse_args()
    project_ids = args.projectid.strip().split(',')
    for project_id in project_ids:
        process(project_id)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response!!
Where do I need to add this bit of code @Allan ? Can you specify that ?

Comment: If you go with the loop approach replace the line `project_id=args.projectid.strip()` with those two lines and indent everything one level.  I don' t how if any of your code keeps state that you will have to deal with.  Another approach is to extract all the code you have after line('=') into a function then call that with each project_id.

Comment: Which approach would be easy? 
For example you mean that I will need to indent all the code below   line(=)  ?
after adding the above two lines?

Comment: I would extract into a function.

Comment: Can you tell me how exactly I can achieve that @Allan ?
I am new to this and I am not sure how to handle it.

Comment: I tried to edit it as per your given information @Allan, It still seems to be not working. 

I have added the code where I edited in the above edited section of my question. 
Can you check what is wrong in that?